# python optparse how to set a args of list?

Tags: python, optparse

I want to pass data to script, like this

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    usage = 'python pull.py [-h <host>][-p <port>][-r <risk>]arg1[,arg2..]'
    parser = OptionParser(usage)
    parser.add_option('-o', '--host', dest='host', default='127.0.0.1',
    ┊   help='mongodb host')
    parser.add_option('-p', '--port', dest='port', default=27017,
    ┊   help="mongodb port")
    parser.add_option('-r', "--risk", dest='risk', default="high",
    ┊   help="the risk of site, choice are 'high', 'middle', 'low', 'all'")
    options, args = parser.parse_args()
```

in this script, if I want to set ./test.py -r high and middle, how can I set `['high', 'middle']` in `optparse`?

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#standard-option-types

> `"choice"` options are a subtype of "string" options. The choices option attribute (a sequence of strings) defines the set of allowed option arguments. `optparse.check_choice()` compares user-supplied option arguments against this master list and raises `OptionValueError` if an invalid string is given.

e.g:

```
parser.add_option('-r', '--risk', dest='risk', default='high',
    type='choice', choices=('high', 'medium', 'low', 'all'),
    help="the risk of site, choice are 'high', 'middle', 'low', 'all'")
```

If you want to be able to pass multiple values to `--risk`, you should use `action="append"`:

> An option’s `action` determines what optparse does when it encounters this option on the command-line. The standard option actions hard-coded into optparse are:
>
> ...
>
> - `"append"` [relevant: `type`, `dest`, `nargs`, `choices`]
>
>   The option must be followed by an argument, which is appended to the list in `dest`. If no default value for `dest` is supplied, an empty list is automatically created when optparse first encounters this option on the command-line. If `nargs` > 1, multiple arguments are consumed, and a tuple of length `nargs` is appended to `dest`.

Also beware of combining `action="append"` with `default=['high']`, because you'll end up in always having 'high' in your `options.risk`.

```
parser.add_option('-r', '--risk', dest='risk', default=[], nargs=1,
    type='choice', choices=('high', 'medium', 'low'), action='append',
    help="the risk of site, choice are 'high', 'middle', 'low'")
```

Usage:

```
>>> options, args = parser.parse_args(['-r','high','-r','medium'])
>>> options.risk
['high', 'medium']
```